# How to fetch value of stdClass Object inside value?

Tags: php, json

```
stdClass Object
(
   [net_type] => Net 1
   [No of Windows] => 2
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Windows1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Width1] => 20
                [Height1] => 10
            )

        [Windows2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Width2] => 40
                [Height2] => 15
            )

    )

   [Pricing/sq ft] => 20
   [Total Area] => 2
   [Total Price] => 5
)
```

I know to get value of `net_type`:

```
$details_decode = json_decode($details);
echo "details==".$details_decode->net_type;
```

But how to get value of `Width1` i.e:

```
echo "windows 1==".$details_decode->Windows1['Width1'];
```

Comment: try `$details_decode[0]->Windows1->Width1`

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: `$details_decode->{'0'}->Windows1->Width1`

Comment: have you checked this?

Comment: I have checked, its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably best to pass a second (`true`) parameter with `json_decode`:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

i.e.:

```
$details_decode = json_decode($details, true);
```

And then access it like an array, this is better since some of the object properties have spaces in them. e.g.:

```
$details_decode['net_type']
$details_decode[0]['Windows1']
$details_decode['Pricing/sq ft']
```

Hope this helps.